# Python parsing: lxml to get just part of a tag's text

Tags: python, screen-scraping, lxml

I'm working in Python with HTML that looks like this. I'm parsing with lxml, but could equally happily use pyquery:

```
<p><span class="Title">Name</span>Dave Davies</p>
<p><span class="Title">Address</span>123 Greyfriars Road, London</p>
```

Pulling out 'Name' and 'Address' is dead easy, whatever library I use, but how do I get the remainder of the text - i.e. 'Dave Davies'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Element can have a [text and a tail attribute](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html#the-element-class) (in the link, search for the word "tail"):

```
import lxml.etree

content='''\
<p><span class="Title">Name</span>Dave Davies</p>
<p><span class="Title">Address</span>123 Greyfriars Road, London</p>'''


root=lxml.etree.fromstring(content,parser=lxml.etree.HTMLParser())
for elt in root.findall('**/span'):
    print(elt.text, elt.tail)

# ('Name', 'Dave Davies')
# ('Address', '123 Greyfriars Road, London')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method -- using xpath:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> doc = html.parse( file )
>>> doc.xpath( '//span[@class="Title"][text()="Name"]/../self::p/text()' )
['Dave Davies']
>>> doc.xpath( '//span[@class="Title"][text()="Address"]/../self::p/text()' )
['123 Greyfriars Road, London']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). I've just started using it, so I'm no expert. Off the top of my head:

```
import BeautifulSoup

text = '''<p><span class="Title">Name</span>Dave Davies</p>
          <p><span class="Title">Address</span>123 Greyfriars Road, London</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(text)

paras = soup.findAll('p')

for para in paras:
    spantext = para.span.text
    othertext = para.span.nextSibling
    print spantext, othertext

[Out]: Name Dave Davies
       Address 123 Greyfriars Road, London
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I also like BeautifulSoup, but I believe it's no longer being maintained, so I'm switching to lxml/pyquery.