# How to extract the 'articleTitle' in the <h3 class="articleTitle"> from a web page?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a web page and there are some PDF urls and their article title. I can use the following code to extract their URLs. I wonder how to extract their articleTitles?

Here is the web page:
http://technical.traders.com/archive/display2.asp?mo=JUL&yr=2008

And here is my code:

```
import lxml.html
import urllib.request as rq

# the url of the page you want to scrape
base_url = 'http://technical.traders.com/archive/display2.asp?mo=JUL&yr=2008'

# fetch the page
res = rq.urlopen(base_url)

# parse the response into an xml tree
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(res.read())

# construct a namespace dictionary to pass to the xpath() call
# this lets us use regular expressions in the xpath
ns = {'re': 'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'}

# iterate over all <a> tags whose href ends in ".pdf" (case-insensitive)
for node in tree.xpath('//a[re:test(@href, "\.pdf$", "i")]', namespaces=ns):

    # print the href, joining it to the base_url
    urlstr = rq.urljoin(base_url, node.attrib['href'])
    print(urlstr)
```

Now I figure out the problem myself. It should be as follow:

```
titles = tree.xpath('//h3[@class="articleTitle"]/text()')  
print(titles)
```

Comment: if this is a self-answered question, you should put the answer part as an **answer**.  It's probably a dupe though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python parsing: lxml to get just part of a tag's text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302248/python-parsing-lxml-to-get-just-part-of-a-tags-text)